# .next() in jquery, will it function to move to the next <div id=id1></div>

Tags: jquery

I want to move to the next  from  can I use .next()?

```
var i=0;
$('#next').bind('click',function(){

 $('#id'+i).next();

i++
});
<div style="width=150px;">
<div id=id1></div>
<div id=id2></div>
<div id=id3></div>
<div id=id4></div>
</div>
```

Next

Thanks
Jean

Comment: @Jean, before you ask, you may want to try it first.

Comment: @Jean, you have an error in your code. `#next` doesn't exist.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @jacob dont be so picky, the question is can i use next to move to the next div, simple.
I dont event have the $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 4):

The `.next()` gets next sibling, if you have html structure:

```
<div id=id1></div>
<div id=id2></div>
<div id=id3></div>
<div id=id4></div>
```

Then, you can walk over each of these divs like this:

```
$('#id1').click(function(){
 // get next that id2
 $(this).next()..........
});
```

**Edit**

Give your divs class also:

```
<div id=id1 class="test"></div>
<div id=id2 class="test"></div>
<div id=id3 class="test"></div>
<div id=id4 class="test"></div>
```

Now with JQuery you can loop each of them like this:

```
var i=0;

$('.test').each(function(){
 // get next and so on
 $('#id'+i).next()..........

 i++;
});
```

Comment: assuming if I had multiple divs with +i, then how do I do it this way?

$('#id'+i).click(function(){
 // get next that id2
 $(this).next()..........
});